# How to wait for changes to field and update UI

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, get-record-notify-change

In LWC js, a json content is updated(appended) in long text field on a record. Each update needs to be captured as a UI row with those details. So, initially we would see 1 row, keep checking the same field for updates every n seconds and when we detect a new append has happened, reflect it in the UI as 2nd row entry. Keep doing this until the json content that is appended has success/fail in status.

```
{
 time: xyz,
 status: successful,
 content: rowContent
}
```

Comment: This is an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What you don't want to do is refresh every second. There's a better way, but we need more information.

Comment: updated with brevity. would notify method be better or directly updating ui vars from controller ?

Comment: My apologies, I was trying to imply that we need to know the nature of the business logic you're trying to implement. The more information we have about the process, the better solution we can provide. Pretend like we're outside consultants that you're trying to hire to implement a feature. The more information we have, the better.

Comment: Please check now, I have updated with details.

Comment: It sounds like you may be looking for a [Change Data Capture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm), rather than polling. This way, the server can tell you when updates happen, rather than repeatedly pinging the server.

Comment: Or use of Lightning Message Service/empApi or similar.

Comment: Thanks but packaging app restricts limit of 5 CDC which are free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works which is an alternative to CDC. Using notifyRecordUpdateAvailable(recordIds) method in a setInterval js method and putting this poller in connectedCallback.
Now, this method keeps checking for updates and in debug logs we get the updated values periodically being checked at our set interval.